# Problems with easy_install --upgrade pytz

Tags: python, easy-install

easy_install was good and very helpful. I have been using it. However, I found it unfunctioning today.

error msg:

```
#easy_install --upgrade pytz
-bash: /usr/local/bin/easy_install: /usr/bin/python2.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I think it is caused by my reinstallation of python and the one I am using is python2.7

So, how can I fix this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Open `/usr/local/bin/easy_install` in a text editor and examine the first line; you'll probably see something like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

This [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) tells the kernel which command it should execute to evaluate the script body. The error message indicates that `/usr/bin/python2.6` is missing.

To fix this and get a working easy_install script, at a minimum you'll need to install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) using your Python 2.7 interpreter and reinstall the packages you depend on (e.g. `pytz`).

Answer (score 2):

`easy_install` is associated with a particular Python instance.  Each Python instance needs to have its own copy.  Thus you need to install a new version of `easy_install` for python2.7. It is supplied by either the traditional [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) project or the more actively maintained [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.17) project.  Follow the installation instructions for either one.